# Is it necessary to explicitly handle Node.js stream errors?

Tags: node.js, node-archiver, archiverjs

I'm using the [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) package in order to compress files and upload them via a stream.

It's my first time using streams in Node.js, and in the documentation of `archiver` I have stumbled upon the following case:

```js
// good practice to catch this error explicitly
archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

In this scenario, is it necessary to listen on `error` just to throw it? Does it make any difference if I simply omit this step?

If not, why is it considered a good practice by the docs?

Comment: not a bad question, but have you tried omitting it and seeing for yourself if there's a difference?

Comment: I did and it doesn't seem to make any noticeable difference. The same error is thrown, but I am wondering if it has some other implications, e.g. whether the stream is closed correctly without the `error` listener etc.